# Which is better -- "scissors-things" or "scissors-thing"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

The other day I loaned an outdoor tool to a friend, and I could not remember what it was called.  I asked him, "**Would you like to borrow my scissors-things?**", showing what I meant.
[image: image of Fiskars-brand lopper]

(I have since learned that this is known as a "lopper".  The round thing is known as a "tennis ball"  included for size comparison.)

As I thought about it later, I wondered if I should have said "scissors-thing" instead of "scissors-things".  This is colloquial usage to begin with, so there may not be a correct way to say something incorrectly.  Non-colloquially, it probably should have been, "my scissors-like thing".  Thus I'm thinking "my scissors thing" would have been better.  Is there some sort of rule that would handle colloquial usage of this sort when dealing with singular-plural items such as scissors or pants.

Comment: Even [pluralia tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) are normally singularised when used attributively (and also when used as a derivational base, like when adding _-like_), so you'd expect _scissor-like_ and _scissor thingy_. Also, I believe the word you were looking for to use with your neighbour was _garden tree branch twig jaw grip scissor tool cutter thingamajig_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet where have you been? No one says "thingamajig" any more.  It's "doohickey".  Geez.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: "*Doohickey*"?! Sounds too saucy for me.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Google Books claims...

> *a **scissor-like** device / instrument* [36](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissors-like%22#tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissor-like%20device%22) / [37](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissors-like%22#tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissor-like%20instrument%22) hits
>    *a **scissors-like** device / instrument* [3](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissors-like%22#tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissors-like%20device%22) / [9](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissors-like%22#tbm=bks&q=%22a%20scissors-like%20instrument%22)

...so by extension the natural form for OP's context would a ***a scissor thing***. There's no reason to pluralise ***things***, which would would only have been "justified" by plural ***scissors*** anyway.

---

Personally, I'd call OP's implement ***loppers*** (pluralised in much the same way as ***scissors***, except I'd never refer to *a **pair** of loppers*). If I wanted to be a bit more vague, I might say *Pass me that **lopper thingy*** (or maybe *...those **lopper thingies***, but never *those loppers things*).

Comment: Thank you for your response.I looked it up, and both "lopper" and "loppers" are used to refer to a single tool.

Comment: (Geez, I wish <Return> would not auto-complete a comment, and for some reason I could not edit it.) @FumbleFingers I up-voted your answer, but I lack sufficient rep for it to show.  I'll have to check out Google Books to find the statistics tool you must have used.  Didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @RichF: Yeah, and by extension from ***scissors, pliers,*** etc., I've no doubt lots of people would be happy with *a pair of loppers*, even if I'm not. But I have a "long pole" instrument in my garden shed that has a short saw-blade as well as cutting pincer jaws on the end. And even though the rod that operates those jaws is broken, we still call that tool ***loppers***, because you can lop off high branches using the saw.

Comment: @RichF I can also recommend Google Ngrams for similar analysis.